# How to add slope value to the end point and find new point?

Tags: geometry

I just draw the line using knowing values (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) fine. Now i need to apply some slope value like m = -1 to the end point and find the new end point. How to do this. Please help some experts. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $$\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\dfrac{y_2-y_o}{x_2-x_o}=\dfrac{y_o-y_1}{x_o-x_1}=m$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).